# Play video without using media player

Tags: android

Am interested in creating own movie which should be started when the button "Start" is clicked. The movie should be played within the app, it should not use the media player or flash player. Is there any ways to play movie without player ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone of the answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
            super.onCreate(icicle); 
            getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT); 
            videoHolder = new VideoView(this); 
            videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); 
            setContentView(videoHolder); 

       //  videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/video.3gp")); 
            videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/video.mp4")); 
            videoHolder.requestFocus(); 
            videoHolder.start();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) Class? I believe that this is what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple use videoview. save file in assets and use videoview in main.xml